# Do not use empty rulesets

Tags: html, css

Ok so I am trying to access a html image from a css script but Im having a problem

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>MB</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">


    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="Top">
            <img class="img-Sale" src="Images/Sale.png" alt="Sale">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCh4b.png)

I have not found any help on this matter on stackoverflow so thats why Im asking

Comment: do you mean that the problem you are facing is a rule witn no css parameters set? I don't get it. You have an `img` element with `class=img-Sale` and then you are using a selector correctly `.img-Sale`. What's wrong?

Comment: Im having a problem with the css script ```.img-Sale {}``` its not identifying the html image class

Comment: how do you know if you didn't put any style in it?

Comment: Ok I just tried it works now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An empty ruleset would be in plain terms leaving this things {} empty.
So, the warning it's basically saying don't do this:

```css
.img-Sale {

}
```

If you write any css inside the curly brackets/braces, for example `{color: black;}`, it will go away.